# Junit test failing for the Observable pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns, junit

I work in a small program using the Observable pattern. The code that I can't modify is provided below.

```
public abstract class ObservableStock {
    
    private double price;
    private StockType name;
    
    public ObservableStock(StockType name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    protected ObservableStock() {
    }
    
    public StockType getName() {
        return name;
    }
    
    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
    
    public abstract void notifyPriceChange(double price);
    
    public abstract void registerStockExchangeCenter(ObserverStockExchangeCenter oc);
}


public abstract class ObserverStockExchangeCenter {
    
    protected Map<StockType, Double> ownedStock;
    
    public ObserverStockExchangeCenter() {
        this.ownedStock = new HashMap<>();
    }
    
    public void buyStock(ObservableStock s) {
        ownedStock.put(s.getName(), 0.0);
        System.out.println("Helo");
    }
    
    //assume we won't change values in the map
    public Map<StockType, Double> getOwnedStock() {
        return ownedStock;
    }
    
    public abstract void observe(ObservableStock o);
    
    public abstract void notifyChange(StockType type, double price);
}

public enum StockType {
    Amazon,
    Google,
}
```

I can modify the classes provided below:

```
public class ObservableStockImpl extends ObservableStock {
    
    private ObserverStockExchangeCenter exchangeCenter;
    public final StockType stockType;
    
    public ObservableStockImpl(StockType name) {
        this.stockType = name;
    }
    
    public void notifyPriceChange(double price) {
        this.exchangeCenter.getOwnedStock().put(stockType, price);
        this.exchangeCenter.notifyChange(stockType, price);
    }
    
    public void registerStockExchangeCenter(ObserverStockExchangeCenter oc) {
        this.exchangeCenter = oc;
    }
    
    public StockType getStockType() {
        return stockType;
    }
}


public class ObserverStockExchangeCenterImpl extends ObserverStockExchangeCenter {
    
    private final List<ObservableStockImpl> observableStocks;
    
    public ObserverStockExchangeCenterImpl() {
        super();
        observableStocks = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    
    public void notifyChange(StockType type, double price) {
        
        for (ObservableStockImpl os : observableStocks) {
            if (os.getStockType().equals(type)) {
                os.setPrice(price);
                os.notifyPriceChange(price);
            }
        }
    }
    
    public void observe(ObservableStock o) {
        observableStocks.add((ObservableStockImpl) o);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void buyStock(ObservableStock s) {
        ObservableStockImpl stock = (ObservableStockImpl) s;
        ownedStock.put(stock.getStockType(), 0.0);
    }
}
```

However, I failed to pass all the tests which are below:

```
@Test
public void stockPriceChangeTest(){

    ObservableStock amazonStock = new ObservableStockImpl(StockType.Amazon);
    ObserverStockExchangeCenter NYStockCenter = new ObserverStockExchangeCenterImpl();
    NYStockCenter.buyStock(amazonStock);
    Map<StockType, Double> boughtStocks = NYStockCenter.getOwnedStock();
    assertEquals(1, boughtStocks.size());
    assertEquals(0,boughtStocks.get(StockType.Amazon),0);

    amazonStock.setPrice(5);
    Map<StockType, Double> boughtStocks2 = NYStockCenter.getOwnedStock();
    assertEquals(1, boughtStocks2.size());

    // failing below
    assertEquals(5,boughtStocks2.get(StockType.Amazon),0);
}
```

The issue is stock price increase not reflected in the code. Can anyone help me to find what is the issue here?

Comment: Here you are not calling notifyPriceChange at the setPrice method. That could be the problem `public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }`

Comment: Use debugger tools on your IDE to set breakpoints and run your app in debug point to find problems like this.

Comment: Yeah, I changed that and it doesn't work either.

Comment: please elaborate "it doesn't work"

Comment: I mean I still get the value 0.0 instead of 5.0

Comment: did you call  notifyPriceChange as this?     `public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
        notifyPriceChange(price);
    }`

Comment: i did the same and got a NullPointerException from `ObservableStockImpl.notifyPriceChange()` It looks you are not setting `exchangeCenter` in your ObservableStockImpl. When i passed it through constructor.. everything worked fine

Comment: Do you manage to pass the test as well? If so, this will be very helpful if you can provide the code as an answer.

Comment: Yes.. Ok. i will post the full code in a while

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we discussed on the comments, here's the working code after the updates.

Problems:

- you were not calling `notifyPriceChange` at `setPrice`
- `exchangeCenter` was not initialized/set at ObservableStockImpl

BONUS Feedback:

- get rid of `ObservableStockImpl` class. You are actually duplicating though you are "extending" `ObservableStock`

Look for comments starting with `// GT` below for the updates i made:

```
package temp;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

public class StockListenerTest {

    @Test
    public void stockPriceChangeTest() {

        ObservableStock amazonStock = new ObservableStockImpl(StockType.Amazon);
        ObserverStockExchangeCenter NYStockCenter = new ObserverStockExchangeCenterImpl();
        
        amazonStock.registerStockExchangeCenter(NYStockCenter); // GT 1 
        
        NYStockCenter.buyStock(amazonStock);
        Map<StockType, Double> boughtStocks = NYStockCenter.getOwnedStock();
        assertEquals(1, boughtStocks.size());
        assertEquals(0, boughtStocks.get(StockType.Amazon), 0);

        amazonStock.setPrice(5);
        Map<StockType, Double> boughtStocks2 = NYStockCenter.getOwnedStock();
        assertEquals(1, boughtStocks2.size());

        // failing below
        assertEquals(5, boughtStocks2.get(StockType.Amazon), 0);
    }
}

abstract class ObservableStock {

    private double price;
    private StockType name;

    public ObservableStock(StockType name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    protected ObservableStock() {
    }

    public StockType getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
        notifyPriceChange(price); //GT 2 - called notifyPriceChange
    }

    public abstract void notifyPriceChange(double price);

    public abstract void registerStockExchangeCenter(ObserverStockExchangeCenter oc);
}


abstract class ObserverStockExchangeCenter {

    protected Map<StockType, Double> ownedStock;

    public ObserverStockExchangeCenter() {
        this.ownedStock = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public void buyStock(ObservableStock s) {
        ownedStock.put(s.getName(), 0.0);
    }

    //assume we won't change values in the map
    public Map<StockType, Double> getOwnedStock() {
        return ownedStock;
    }

    public abstract void observe(ObservableStock o);

    public abstract void notifyChange(StockType type, double price);
}

enum StockType {
    Amazon,
    Google,
}

class ObservableStockImpl extends ObservableStock {

    private ObserverStockExchangeCenter exchangeCenter;
    public final StockType stockType;

    public ObservableStockImpl(StockType name ) { 
        this.stockType = name;
    }

    public void notifyPriceChange(double price) {
        this.exchangeCenter.getOwnedStock().put(stockType, price);
        this.exchangeCenter.notifyChange(stockType, price);
    }

    public void registerStockExchangeCenter(ObserverStockExchangeCenter oc) {
        this.exchangeCenter = oc;
    }

    public StockType getStockType() {
        return stockType;
    }
}

class ObserverStockExchangeCenterImpl extends ObserverStockExchangeCenter {

    private final List<ObservableStockImpl> observableStocks;

    public ObserverStockExchangeCenterImpl() {
        super();
        observableStocks = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void notifyChange(StockType type, double price) {
        for (ObservableStockImpl os : observableStocks) {
            if (os.getStockType().equals(type)) {
                os.setPrice(price);
                os.notifyPriceChange(price);
            }
        }
    }

    public void observe(ObservableStock o) {
        observableStocks.add((ObservableStockImpl) o);
    }

    @Override
    public void buyStock(ObservableStock s) {
        ObservableStockImpl stock = (ObservableStockImpl) s;
        ownedStock.put(stock.getStockType(), 0.0);
    }
}
```

Comment: what its not allowed?

Comment: You are getting NullPointerException because you are not setting the ObserverStockExchangeCenter  to ObservableStock in your test. I've updated my code to have fewer change this time

Comment: gtiwari333 I provided an answer if you would like to see it.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer is correct but, he modified the test method which is not allowed. I have done with w/o any test method modification with slight changes.

The trick is in this overridden method where we register to the exchange and then move back to the mother method using the super keyword:

```
@Override
public void buyStock(ObservableStock observableStock) {
    observableStock.registerStockExchangeCenter(this);
    super.buyStock(observableStock);
}


class ObservableStockImpl extends ObservableStock {
    
    private ObserverStockExchangeCenter exchangeCenter;
    public final StockType stockType;
    
    public ObservableStockImpl(StockType name) {
        super(name);
        this.stockType = name;
        this.exchangeCenter = new ObserverStockExchangeCenterImpl();
    }
    
    public void notifyPriceChange(double price) {
        this.exchangeCenter.getOwnedStock().put(stockType, price);
    }
    
    public void registerStockExchangeCenter(ObserverStockExchangeCenter oc) {
        this.exchangeCenter = oc;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void setPrice(double price) {
        notifyPriceChange(price);
    }
}



class ObserverStockExchangeCenterImpl extends ObserverStockExchangeCenter {
    
    private final List<ObservableStock> observableStocks;
    
    public ObserverStockExchangeCenterImpl() {
        super();
        observableStocks = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    
    public void notifyChange(StockType type, double price) {
        
        for (ObservableStock observableStock : observableStocks) {
            if (observableStock == null) {
                continue;
            }
            
            if (observableStock.getName().equals(type)) {
                observableStock.notifyPriceChange(price);
            }
        }
    }
    
    public void observe(ObservableStock o) {
        observableStocks.add(o);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void buyStock(ObservableStock observableStock) {
        observableStock.registerStockExchangeCenter(this);
        super.buyStock(observableStock);
    }
}
```